# using fscanf to read stream of data from file

Tags: c

I need to read a steam of data from file, it looks like :

```
0   1.8750  274.90  0   0   0
1   3.7500  370.50  0   1   0
2   7.5000  463.50  0   2   0
```

so I use :

```
fscanf(p,"%d%f%f%d%d%d",&a, &b,&c,&d,&t,&q);
```

when I try to see if it reads correctly, I used:

```
printf("A %d",a);
printf("B %f",b);
```

the output :

```
A 0B -1.882607
```

So, why fscanf doesn't read float correctly ??

Comment: Show your variable declarations

Comment: Are b, c floats or doubles? What operating system/compiler do you use?

Comment: It should work provided `b,c` are `float` and `a,d,t,q` are `int`

Comment: It was able to open the file properly?

Answer (score 1):

The *likely* source of the problem is **mis-match `fscanf()` directives**
  or
**incomplete** `fscanf()` read.  Maybe due to an unopened file or unexpected input text.

```
A 0B -1.882607
| || +--------- b value -1.882607
| |+----------- Letters B space
| +------------ a value 0
+-------------- Letters A space
```

---

Insure your variables are the following types:

```
int a,d,t,q;
float b,c;
```

Check the result of the fscanf()

```
int result = fscanf(p,"%d%f%f%d%d%d",&a, &b,&c,&d,&t,&q);
if (result != 6) {
  printf("Error, unexpected return value:%d\n", result);
}
```

---

Additional info form the OP would help.